# How to Get a Rainbow

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

Why I need a Rainbow is because I want a Super Fever (or Fever) in Pokemon Rumble World. I have tried beating the pokemon with my Hydregion (Strength 714)
with doing my best it still did not work.

Comment: Note that even if you get rainbows after completing a stage that there is no guarantee the next will have fever or super fever. I have got 3 rainbows without immediate fevers quite a few times now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be random, as I know there's no "trick" to obtain a rainbow after the stage.
Maybe doing a large combo helps obtaining it, but there are no official evidences of this.

The only thing you can do is play you balloons over and over, you'll eventually get a rainbow sooner or later.